# How to set blank as default value in the property which is of type DateTime?

Tags: c#

I have created a property which is of type DateTime. When I am setting this property value in label on InvokePropertyChanged() event, it shows default value (1/1/0001 12:00:00). How can I set blank text if properties not have valid date?

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private DateTime? _dDateTime = null;

public DateTime PostedDateTime
{
    get
    {
        return _dDateTime.HasValue ? _dDateTime.Value : DateTime.Now;
    }
    set
    {
        _dDateTime = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PostedDateTime"));
    }
}

public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
        Refresh();
    }

    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("PostedDateTime"))
      lblDateTimeDt.Text = PostedDateTime.ToString();// setting datetime in label

}
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to use a nullable DateTime and set it to null, yes? That, or you can create a DateTime field with a getter and a setter property, which returns "blank", when the value was not set.

Answer (score 0):

you can test the value before assgin

```
public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
       handler(this, e);
       Refresh();
    }

    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("PostedDateTime"))
    lblDateTimeDt.Text = PostedDateTime == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : PostedDateTime.ToString();
```

}